# unable to add filter on a collection in Meteor helper

Tags: meteor

I've got a sort filter working, in a helper, on a collection that shows "goals" ordered by date. I'm trying to add a filter that also only shows goals that have a status of 1.

/server/publications.js

```
Meteor.publish("goals", function() {
    return Goals.find();
});
```

/client/main.js

```
Meteor.subscribe("goals");
```

/client/views/goals_list.js

```
Template.goalsList.helpers({
    goals: function() {
        return Goals.find({}, {sort: {submitted: -1}}, {status: 1});
    }
});
```

The sort on submitted works fine, and continues working with the addition of the status, but I still see all the goals, not just the ones with a status of 1.

I've tried this, and many more ideas:

```
return Goals.find({}, {sort: {submitted: -1}}, {filter: {status: 1}});
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directives which limit the returned documents based on their contents belong in the [selector](http://docs.meteor.com/#selectors) argument to `find`. So in your case:

```js
return Goals.find({status: 1}, {sort: {submitted: -1}});
```

Comment: thanks much. A bit obvious I guess. How would the sort know what to sort when it's backwards, eh?